# How to compare different subsamples in mixed logit model?

Tags: regression, logistic, group-differences

When conducting a discrete choice experiment, we additionally split the sample randomly in a control and treatment group testing one specific effect and would like to now examine whether the treatment has any statistically significant effect on the estimated parameters. However, we're unsure how to compare the estimates after running separate mixed logistic regression for the two groups. Specifically, given that it is a logistic model, we assume that based on Allison (1999) and Williams (2009) we cannot simply compare the estimates and their confidence intervals, but are unsure how to incorporate the estimated standard deviation of the random parameters into the comparison.

While another way would be to incorporate the effect of the treatment into the model via an interaction, we would not like to do this as this approach has recently been rejected by the reviewers of some previous research.

What would be the best way to test for significant differences in model parameters between the two groups, incorporating the heterogeneity?

Thank you very much for your help.